# OpenGL instancing everything?

Tags: performance, opengl, 3d, rendering, instance

Is it possible to use instancing for every object in OpenGL, instead of using it only for objects sharing same vertex data ?

If we can instance matrix attribute data, then we could also instance vertex data attributes, by using glVertexAttribDivisor for every attribute and not only for matrix attributes, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course use completely different position data per instance. But you cannot change the vertex count between the instances. Also, when using indexed rendering, the indices are the samer for all instances. Instancing only makes sense if you have a some attributes which are actually shared between the instances, and if all the instances have the same primitive type and count.

If you want to draw multiple different objects with a single draw call, you should have a look at [multi draw indirect](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multi_draw_indirect.txt).